# Is it true $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=n-i+1}^n i^{-a}j^{-a} \ge \int_1^n x^{-a}(\int_{n-x+1}^n y^{-a}\, \mathrm{d}y)\, \mathrm{d} x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, definite-integrals

> **Conjecture 1**: For each $n\ge 1$ and $a \ge 2$,
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=n-i+1}^n i^{-a}j^{-a} \ge \int_1^n x^{-a}\left(\int_{n-x+1}^n y^{-a}\, \mathrm{d}y\right) \mathrm{d} x.$$

This is related to this question:
[Speed of Convergence for some series (double sum)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446974/speed-of-convergence-for-some-series-double-sum)

I want to know if Conjecture 1 is true. I did some numerical experiment which supports the claim.

**Some discussions**:

**Fact 1**: Let $f(x)$ be a continuously differentiable function on $[1, \infty)$. Then, for each $m\ge 1$,
$$\int_m^{m+1} f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_m^{m+1} (x - \lfloor x\rfloor)f'(x)\,\mathrm{d} x = f(m+1).
$$
(*Note*: Use IBP and $\lfloor x\rfloor = m$ for all $m \le x < m + 1$.)

Let
$$S := \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=n-i+1}^n i^{-a}j^{-a}.$$

Using Fact 1, it is not difficult to obtain
\begin{align*}
 S
 &= \sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{j=n-i+2}^n i^{-a}j^{-a} + n^{-a} + \sum_{i=2}^n i^{-a}(n-i+1)^{-a}\\[6pt]
 &= \int_1^n x^{-a}\left(\int_{n-x+1}^n y^{-a}\, \mathrm{d}y\right) \mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 &\quad + \int_1^n  (x - \lfloor x\rfloor) \left(x^{-a}(n-x+1)^{-a} - a x^{-a - 1}\int_{n-x+1}^n y^{-a}\,\mathrm{d} y
 \right)\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &\quad + n^{-a} + \sum_{i=2}^n i^{-a}
 \left((n-i+1)^{-a} - \int_{n-i+1}^n (y - \lfloor y\rfloor) ay^{-a - 1}\, \mathrm{d} y\right).
\end{align*}

**Fact 2**: For all $n\ge 1$ and $1 \le i \le n$ and $a \ge 2$,
$$(n-i+1)^{-a} - \int_{n-i+1}^n (y - \lfloor y\rfloor) ay^{-a - 1}\, \mathrm{d} y \ge 0.$$

**Question 1**: I guess that
$$\int_1^n  (x - \lfloor x\rfloor) \left(x^{-a}(n-x+1)^{-a} - a x^{-a - 1}\int_{n-x+1}^n y^{-a}\,\mathrm{d} y
\right)\mathrm{d} x \ge 0.$$
Is it true?
*Note*: $x^{-a}(n-x+1)^{-a} - a x^{-a - 1}\int_{n-x+1}^n y^{-a}\,\mathrm{d} y\ge 0$ is not true.

**Question 2**: I also guess that
$$n^{-a} + \int_1^n  (x - \lfloor x\rfloor) \left( - a x^{-a - 1}\int_{n-x+1}^n y^{-a}\,\mathrm{d} y
\right)\mathrm{d} x \ge 0.$$
Is it true?

Any comments and solutions are welcome and appreciated.

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

Simply use the fact
\begin{align*}
 &\int_{n-i+1}^n (y - \lfloor y\rfloor) ay^{-a - 1}\, \mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 =\,& \sum_{k=n-i+1}^{n-1}(k^{-a} - (k + 1)^{-a})\\[6pt]
 &\qquad
 - \sum_{k=n-i+1}^{n-1} k^{-a}(k+1)\left(\frac{a}{k+1}-1 + \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^{-a}\right).
\end{align*}
and note that
$$\frac{a}{k+1}-1 + \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^{-a} \ge 0.$$

Comment: Does it appear true numerically?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I did some numerical experiment which supports the claim.